# Laravel Eloquent table relationship with $id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to fetch a specific post from posts table with some users information from users table. i have used 
$id to fetch only the user with same id, But whenever i tried to fetch the information from both tables it prints this error

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
>   where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` inner join
>   `posts` on `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `id` = 6)"

Below is my User Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email','phone', 'username', 'password', 'admin', 'address', 'description', 'approved_at',
];
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

And my Post model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model

{
protected $guarded = [];
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}
}
```

And my route

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){
    $posts = User::join('posts','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('posts')->with('posts', $posts);
});
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Consider to use eager loading. You already defined the relationship, so you can do `Post::with('user')->find($id);` to "fetch a specific post from posts table with some users information"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append users with id in your route like this

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){
    $posts = User::join('posts','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->where('users.id', $id)->get();
    return view('posts')->with('posts', $posts);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i mnaged to fetch the information from both tables. The problem is i was using the wrong column for user id (id instead of users.id).

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to get the posts of the users with `id = 6`, so you just want to edit your code like this:

```php
Route::get('/post/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){
    $posts = User::join('posts','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->where('users.id', $id)->get(); //Change here
    return view('posts')->with('posts', $posts);
});
```

The error has nothing to do with Laravel since you are not using relations but just because `posts` has an `id` field too  and it's ambiguous.

If you want to use Laravel relations you could just do something like

```php
$user = App\User::find(6);
$posts = $user->posts()->get();
```

[More here.](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Answer (score 1):

it return specific post with user details

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', function(Request $request, $id){
    $posts = Post::with('user')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('posts')->with('posts', $posts);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a relationship setup between these 2 Models you can use the relationship instead of joining yourself:

```
$post = Post::with('user')->find($id);

$post->user->name;
```

If you want to do the join yourself you have to resolve the ambiguous `id` field, since both tables joined have an `id` field:

```
...->where('posts.id', $id)->first();
```